# How to avoid db not close and cursor exception

Tags: android, database, cursor

```
02-02 14:31:34.048: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(359): Releasing statement in a finalizer. Please ensure that you explicitly call close() on your cursor: SELECT * FROM 
02-02 14:31:34.048: WARN/SQLiteCompiledSql(359): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
02-02 14:31:34.129: ERROR/Database(359): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
02-02 14:31:34.129: ERROR/Database(359):     at
```

How to avoid this exception ?? Pls help

My code is given below :

```
 **DataSQLHelper .class**

public class DataSQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   public DataSQLHelper (Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "create table " + TABLE + "( " + BaseColumns._ID
    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + ID + " text, "
    + PASSWORD + " text, " + ACTIVE + " text, " + STATUS
    + " text);";
    db.execSQL(sql);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
if (oldVersion >= newVersion)
    return;

String sql = null;
if (oldVersion == 1)
    sql = "alter table " + TABLE + " add note text;";
if (oldVersion == 2)
    sql = "";


if (sql != null)
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

        @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
                   super.close();


    }

}


    ***Test_Java .java***

     public class Test_Java extends Activity {
  DataSQLHelper helData;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {      

        helData= new DataSQLHelper(this);
     cursor = getData();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    setContentView(R.layout.view);


} catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    } // onCreate Ends



private Cursor getData() {
try {
     db = helData.getReadableDatabase();
     cursor = db.query(DataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, null,
        null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Exception Occured : " + ex.toString());
    return null;
}

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   System.out.println("onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (db!=null){
                   db.close();
                }
    if (cursor!=null){
                    cursor.close();
    }

    if ( helData!=null){
        helData.close();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the exception. I was calling

```
 db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
```

twice thats why the exception is thrown

Answer (score 4):

You should reverse the close statements within your onDestroy() method.
First close the cursor, then the db:

```
if (cursor!=null){
    cursor.close();
}
if (db!=null){
    db.close();
}
```

You basically need to reverse the order of creating/opening db and cursor.

Also note that the db/cursor in the example is opened in onCreate() which is a callback from the system. You may want to close the cursor/db before leaving that method. You are free to cache the DataSQLHelper in your
application.

In my application [Zwitscher](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA), I have put the whole db/cursor handling with the methods of the SQLHelper class so that the layers above do not have to care about it. See its [TweetDB](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TweetDB.java#L217) class.

Comment: i have given like this Heiko.. but still getting the same exception .. and the line is inside the method getData() ; db = helData.getReadableDatabase();
 &   cursor = db.query(DataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, null,
        null, null, null, null);

Comment: this is my code  protected void onDestroy() {
       
        super.onDestroy();
        if (cursor!=null){
           
            cursor.close();
        }
        
        if (db!=null){
            
            db.close();
            
        }
       
        
       
        
    }

Comment: im also getting the same exception .. Pls Help

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer - have a look at the linked TweetDB class for how I am doing it.

Comment: You close the database after every db-operation? Doing that makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Warren How would you do it - given the fact that an application can be paused at any time and that there are multiple path back into the application?

Comment: And opening/closing the DB is not that expensive - there are much longer running things happening.

Comment: I would extend the application class, open the database there in `onCreate` and close it in `onTerminate`. Keeping the instance of the database in the application enable you to access the database from everywhere at any time. "is not that expensive" doesn't mean it is cheap. A short sample can  be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499420/how-can-i-clear-a-sqlite-database-each-time-i-start-my-app/4499476#4499476

Comment: @warren according to the docs, onTerminate() is not called on real devices. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate() This actually worries me, as if a writable DB is not closed, there is no guarantee that all data is written. Especially as an app to terminate is just killed away.

Comment: @Heiko Rupp I have given @Override protected void onDestroy() { close(); if (db!=null){ db.close(); } super.onDestroy(); } public void close() { eventsData.close(); } ..But still the exception is showing