# how to drop database in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using SQLite in android. I want to drop the database.

For example: `mysql- drop database dbname`

How do I implement this code in SQLite?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The concept of creating or dropping a database is not meaningful for an embedded database engine like SQLite.  It only has meaning with a client-sever database system, such as used by MySQL or Postgres.

To create a new database, just do `sqlite_open()` or from the command line `sqlite3 databasefilename`.

To drop a database, delete the file.

Reference: **[sqlite - Unsupported SQL](http://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSql)**

Comment: An embedded db engine means for me a file based database as seen with sqlite, so deleting the db.db file will drop the db.

Answer (score 61):

to delete your app database try this:

```
 this.deleteDatabase("databasename.db");
```

this will delete the database file

Comment: you must have access to the context to do this.

Comment: +1 for the answer... I just wanted to downgrade the database which is not allowed so I had to delete the database... :)

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but it IS possible to downgrade your database. It's just disabled by default. You would need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

You can drop `tables` by issuing an SQL Command as you would normally. If you want to drop the whole database you'll have to delete the file. You can delete the file located under

`data/data/com.your.app.name/database/[databasefilename]`

you can do this from the eclipse view called "FileBrowser" out of the "Android" Category for example. Or directly on your emulator or phone.

Answer (score 7):

try this :

```
 context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

[How to delete SQLite database from Android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406067/how-to-delete-sqlite-database-from-android-programmatically)

Comment: Is .db included or not after the db name ?

Answer (score 5):

From http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=UnsupportedSql

> To create a new database, just do
>   sqlite_open(). To drop a database,
>   delete the file.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to delete database programatically you can use `deleteDatabase` from `Context` class:

> **deleteDatabase(String name)**
>   Delete an existing private SQLiteDatabase associated with this Context's application package.

Answer (score 5):

```
SQLite database FAQ: How do I drop a SQLite database?

People used to working with other databases are used to having a "drop database" command, but in SQLite there is no similar command. The reason? In SQLite there is no "database server" -- SQLite is an embedded database, and your database is entirely contained in one file. So there is no need for a SQLite drop database command.

To "drop" a SQLite database, all you have to do is delete the SQLite database file you were accessing.
```

copy from http://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-drop-database-how

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQLiteOpenHelper you can do this

```
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(new File(myPath));
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite saves data to a file. Leverage the methods tailored to the specific OS so you can delete the file. I.E. with Android use the System.IO.File.Delete() method.

Here is some code showing what I used to create and delete my SQLite database on an android device in C#:

```
public class SQLite_DB 
{
    private string databasePath;

    public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection()
    {
        databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "sqlite_db.db3");
        SQLiteAsyncConnection database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);
        return database;
    }

    public bool DeleteDatabase()
    {
        File.Delete(databasePath);

        if (File.Exists(databasePath))
        return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

You may also be able to use the Java.IO.File class.