# How to delete SQLite database android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, delete-file

I want to delete the SQLite database from device. I am trying to delete it but its not getting delete, because I can see the old records of database.

Trying to delete like this:

```
        deleteDatabase(Constants.DATABASE_NAME);

            DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            db.createDatabase();
```

Constants :

```
    public class Constants {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 12;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsApp";
}
```

DatabaseHelper :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String USER_TABLE = "userTable";
    private static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "userName";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL_ID = "emailId";
    private static final String KEY_MOBILE_NO = "mobileNo";
    private static final String KEY_PROFILE_IMAGE = "profileImage";
    private static final String KEY_FULL_NAME = "fullName";
    private static final String KEY_DEVICE_ID = "deviceId";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD ="password";
    private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "userId";
    private static final String KEY_JOB_TITLE = "jobTitle";
    private static final String KEY_WORK_ADDRESS = "workAddress";
    private static final String KEY_WORK_PHONE = "workPhone";
    private static final String KEY_HOME_ADDRESS = "homeAddress";


    private static final String CONTACT_TABLE = "contactTable";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACT_NAME = "contactName";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACT_EMAIL_ID = "contactEmailId";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACT_MOBILE_NO = "contactMobileNo";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACT_PROFILE_IMAGE = "contactProfileImage";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACT_ID = "contactId";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACT_FULL_NAME = "fullName";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACT_JOB_TITLE = "jobTitle";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACT_WORK_ADDRESS = "workAddress";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACT_WORK_PHONE = "workPhone";
    private static final String KEY_CONTACT_HOME_ADDRESS = "homeAddress";

    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);
        //3rd argument to be passed is CursorFactory instance
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        createTable(db);

    }

    public void createDatabase(){
        context.deleteDatabase(Constants.DATABASE_NAME + ".db");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    }


    public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE + "("
                + KEY_USER_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_MOBILE_NO + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PROFILE_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_FULL_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DEVICE_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_JOB_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_HOME_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_WORK_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_WORK_PHONE + " TEXT " + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);

        String CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + CONTACT_TABLE + "("
                + KEY_CONTACT_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CONTACT_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CONTACT_MOBILE_NO + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CONTACT_EMAIL_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CONTACT_PROFILE_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CONTACT_FULL_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CONTACT_JOB_TITLE+ " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CONTACT_WORK_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CONTACT_WORK_PHONE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CONTACT_HOME_ADDRESS + " TEXT " + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE);

    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CONTACT_TABLE);

        context.deleteDatabase(Constants.DATABASE_NAME + ".db");

        createTable(db);

    }

}
```

I also tried to delete only tables, but its not getting delete.

What can be the issue? Can anyone help please? Thank you..

Comment: what about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326918/how-to-drop-database-in-sqlite

Comment: Where is your delete method?

Answer (score 3):

```
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(new File(myPath));
```

OR

```
 context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

for more detail..
[How to delete SQLite database from Android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406067/how-to-delete-sqlite-database-from-android-programmatically)

Comment: I tried with  context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME); but still its not getting delete. @Nikhil Boras

Comment: onUpgrade method  swap last two line up to down.. after deleting you create new one.

Comment: how will it create new database if I swap? @Nikhil Borad

Comment: dosen't help..@Nikhil Borad

Comment: how to get path for your this answer : String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; @ Nikhil Borad

Comment: context.getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.YOUR_DB_NAME);             it returns db fullpath.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close all Database connections before deleting. Else you'll have to restart the application to see the change

Comment: If I am restarting the application still I cant see the change. @Anto

Comment: Did you make sure all connection to DB were closed before deleting ?

Answer (score 0):

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

When this line gets run, the database should be deleted.
This is a proper way to delete database file after database was created by getDatabasePath()//