# Android: Flush sqlite database when app killed

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, kill

I'm working on an app that stores some information inside an SQLite DB.

My problem is that I'd like to clear all data from the database when the app gets killed or the phone restarted.
Does anybody know I can I do this?

Thanks
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There probably isn't a totally foolproof way of doing this. You could clear the data in onDestroy() of your activity, though it might not get called if someone uses something like a task killer (pretty sure about this).
A better option would be to clear the data the next time you start the app.

Comment: Thanks I decided to clear the data at the App restart, it should work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499420/how-can-i-clear-a-sqlite-database-each-time-i-start-my-app/4499476#4499476) of subclassing Application and performing your table dropping/creating there rather than in onStop and onPause.

Comment: Except that `Application.onTerminate()` is only called when running on the emulator. There is no application-level destroy callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the in-memory flag by passing null as your db name. That means the db won't be stored on sd card at all so no need to clear it before the app dies.