# Save Data before Auto Update

Tags: android

When an automatic update occurs, the old date save in the preferences for my app gets delete.
**How can i prevent this deletion?**
I want that when my app auto updates , it does not delete my old data saved.

Comment: @ChiragPatel.. no code required for this man.
I asked a simple query.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this will be a good solution but just a suggestion you can try.

**step 1:** whenever you changeg (add/edit/remove) your data store it in permanent storage, you may try any of the following

> ```
>  a. save the data in file in sd card
>  b. store the data to your remote server or 
>  c. store in internal memory of the phone.
> ```
>
> (I am not sure whether it will persists after update at case c, for reference can check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

**Step 2:**  creae a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to the `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` Intent. So you know when your application package is updated. NOw read the data again from the storage where you saved the data ( either 1a/1b/1c)

Caution: It is not a good thing to save user data without his concern.

Comment: Thanks for a detail reply StinePike... I am saving the data in shared prefs already but now i wanna ask that does data gets deleted on auto update ??
According to my R&D, the data is saved with the package name so auto update shall not change it..

Comment: I knew that SharedPreference are stored even after updating .. but according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10201011/931982 it may be delete sometimes.

Comment: but in every other places I found that SharedPreferences preserves data  except cleardata or uninstall. But as you told that your data from preference lost I thought You have already tried SharedPreference

Comment: ok.. yeah i am saving my data in shared preferences.
Thanks for the info man

Answer (score 1):

Android save your SharedPreference under /data/data/your package name/shared_prefs

Generally, update application won't delete your sharedPreference.

```
private void replaceNonSystemPackageLI(PackageParser.Package deletedPackage,
        PackageParser.Package pkg, int parseFlags, int scanMode, UserHandle user,
        String installerPackageName, PackageInstalledInfo res) {
    ...
    // First delete the existing package while retaining the data directory
    if (!deletePackageLI(pkgName, null, true, PackageManager.DELETE_KEEP_DATA,
            res.removedInfo, true)) {
        // If the existing package wasn't successfully deleted
        res.returnCode = PackageManager.INSTALL_FAILED_REPLACE_COULDNT_DELETE;
        deletedPkg = false;
    } else {
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

I think you need to check the following:

1. Is your device a rooted device? Apps on a rooted device can delete anything they want.
2. Did you use a different package name in that updated apk?

Comment: No my device is not rooted and my package name is same for each update.
I just got my data deleted once because of any unknown reason but i guess each time it is not getting deleted.
I will check this issue precisely on the next update and if it happen again then surely i will look for your proposed solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: np, this is an unexpected behavior, so maybe you need to provde more information about your app or your device for a more helpful solution. :)

Comment: What about /data/data/PKGNAME/files/ directory? Will that survive a package update as well? Thx.

Comment: I haven't checked the code, but I think that will survive during a update. @Bram