# Clear sqlite database at a certain point of an application

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to clear my SQLite db every time I hit a particular spot in my application.

I intended on just making a method that I could call called `resetTables()`, but this seems to be more challenging than I expected because I don't really know where to place it. Here is a snippet.

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

        }
        public void reset(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        }
```

I'm getting a yellow line under reset and I can't call this method in my code. Any ideas?

Note this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499420/how-can-i-clear-a-sqlite-database-each-time-i-start-my-app) is similar, but couldn't get it to help me.

### This worked:

```
public void resetTables(){
        mDb.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: "I can't call this method in my code" -- why can't you?

Comment: The method reset() is undefined for the type DBAdapter

Comment: I hit a particular spot in my application, what is that spot?

Comment: Then apparently you did not define `reset()` on `DBAdapter`. What class did you define it on?

Comment: "particular spot" is when I hit a button to start a "new game". I defined reset() right below onCreate. EDIT: So reset() was being defined in DatabaseHelper, so I moved it down and now I don't get any errors in my DBAdapter class. But when I try to call it in my code I need a parameter to pass through, but I don't have any to send in.       `test_db.reset();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create one method where you create your database and table.

```
 /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
        db.close();
    }
```

and call above method using on your button click event.

Comment: I get a red line under `.getWritableDatabase()`

Comment: you should pass the context to your database handler class

Comment: Just left the db.delete statement and took out everything else and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have done it by this way...

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onOpen(db);

     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
}
```

and yes it definitely worked for me..:)

Comment: But in my application, I open my database many times, and don't want to reset it when it's opened. I want to create a separate method like `reset()`